# How to pick certain amount of random excel cells with text and combine them in a string

Tags: excel, string, list, random

I have a big list with about ~300 hashtags where I want to pick a certain amount (like 10 hashtags) randomly. Is it possible without VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way of doing it, though it relies on your Excel being recent enough to support these functions:

- LET
- UNIQUE
- RANDARRAY
- SEQUENCE

[image]

With this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,LET(rng,$B$3:$B$13,n,ROWS(rng),idx,UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(n*n,1,1,n,TRUE)),s,SEQUENCE($E$1),INDEX(rng,INDEX(idx,s))))
```

It's a bit lengthy, but works around the observation that RANDARRAY() can return duplicate values by getting many more random numbers than are needed, and then taking the first x values.

NB. If the number of tags you want is small compared to the total available, then you probably don't need the (n*n) and can just use (n).

Hat-tips to @SpencerBarnes and @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: Yes not only using `UNIQUE()` function but the `ROWS()` or `COUNTA()` Function was needed. there.

Answer (score 1):

on **Office 365:**

```
=CONCAT(INDEX(A1:A300, RANDARRAY(10,0, 1, 300, TRUE)))
```

Where `A1:A300` is your list of hashtags, and `1, 300,` is the start and end of the list.

Removing the `CONCAT()` function from the outside of the formula will output a spilled range rather than a concatenated string.

Comment: From the Excel help here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/randarray-function-21261e55-3bec-4885-86a6-8b0a47fd4d33 the third example suggests that values can be duplicated. The OP doesn't mention duplication, but possibly they might like unique values?

Comment: @DS_London yes it needs to be wrapped within an `UNIQUE()` then it works =)